# Handle streaming events with AVPlayer

Tags: ios, xcode, stream, avfoundation, avplayer

I'm building an app which plays an audio stream (from a webradio).

I'm using `AVPlayer` for it.

1. I'd like to know how you would handle `AVPlayer's` "buffering" when the connection is slow or when the user just clicked "play". I want to detect that `AVPlayer` is "buffering" to display an `UIActivityIndicatorView`.
2. Same question while running in the background. What should I do if buffering in this case?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### For the first question

You can refer to my answer on this topic [ios avplayer trigger streaming is out of buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880817/ios-avplayer-trigger-streaming-is-out-of-buffer)

#### For the second

Here is how I solved this same problem:

Inside where you handle the event for buffer empty add this code:

```
    if (object == playerItem && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"playbackBufferEmpty"])
    {
        if (playerItem.playbackBufferEmpty) {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"message" object:@"Buffering..."];
            
            if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateBackground)
            {
                task = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^(void) {
                }];
            }
        }
    }
```

Now you will have to stop this background task after your buffer is ready to go again:

```
if (object == playerItem && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp"])
{
    if (playerItem.playbackLikelyToKeepUp)
    {
        [player play];
        
        if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateBackground)
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:task];
            task = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

ps: task is declared on my .h file as `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier task;`

Comment: Why do you need a bg task here? I don't see the connection.

Comment: This happens because when your application is in background and for some reason your stream is halted iOS will terminate your player and you will not be able to continue once you start receive streaming again. So with this we can cheat on iOS to make it think that your player is still working.

Comment: Do you need anything inside your task block? Or does that exist just to keep a loop running on the app delegate?

Answer (score 10):

I have found the solution to this problem.

```
if (self.avPlayer.currentItem.playbackLikelyToKeepUp == NO) 
{
    // Show activity indicator
}
```

Comment: What method did you put that in?

Comment: Ruben Martinez Jr  - use timer for check (1 sec optimal) , on KeepUp ==YES  timer.invalidate()

Answer (score 2):

**For Swift 3**

This works fine for me, maybe it can help, call `self?.bufferState()` inside `addPeriodicTimeObserver`

```
    private func bufferState() {
    if let currentItem = self.avPlayer.currentItem {
        if currentItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatus.readyToPlay {
            if currentItem.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp {
                print("Playing ")
            } else if currentItem.isPlaybackBufferEmpty {
                print("Buffer empty - show loader")
            }  else if currentItem.isPlaybackBufferFull {
                print("Buffer full - hide loader")
            } else {
                print("Buffering ")
            }
        } else if currentItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatus.failed {
            print("Failed ")
        } else if currentItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatus.unknown {
            print("Unknown ")
        }
    } else {
        print("avPlayer.currentItem is nil")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AVPlayerItem* mPlayerItem;
```

---

```
if(context == AVPlayerDemoPlaybackViewControllerCurrentItemBufferEmptyContext) 
{
    if (object == self.mPlayerItem && [path isEqualToString:@"playbackBufferEmpty"]) 
    {
        if (self.mPlayerItem.playbackBufferEmpty)
        {
            playBufferEmpty = TRUE;
            [indicator startAnimating];
            [vidStreaminglabel setText:@"Buffering..."];
            [vidStreaminglabel setHidden:NO];
        }
    }
}

else if(context == AVPlayerDemoPlaybackViewControllerCurrentItemPlayBackBufferFullContext)
{
    if (object == mPlayerItem && [path isEqualToString:@"playbackBufferFull"]){
        if (self.mPlayerItem.playbackBufferFull) {
            [mPlayer play];
        }
    }
}

else if (context == AVPlayerDemoPlaybackViewControllerCurrentItemPlayBackLikelyToKeepUpContext)
{
    if (object == mPlayerItem && [path isEqualToString:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp"])
    {
         if(self.mPlayerItem.playbackLikelyToKeepUp)
         {
             // Autoplay after buffer 
             if(!(mRestoreAfterScrubbingRate != 0.f || [self.mPlayer rate] != 0.f))
             {
                 if (self.presentingViewController) {
                     [mPlayer play];
                 }

                 playBufferEmpty = FALSE;
                 [indicator stopAnimating];
                 [vidStreaminglabel setHidden:YES];
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is context and where does it come from? Can you please include the method declaration and / or calls?

Comment: Please give proper explanation Don't waste time of others !!