# AVPlayerItem strange buffer observer

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer

I'm using AVPlayer to play streamed network audio. I observer status of the streamed item as this post:

[ios avplayer trigger streaming is out of buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880817/ios-avplayer-trigger-streaming-is-out-of-buffer)

Work seems well, but I encounter a strange problem. I meet the key "playbackLikelyToKeepUp" before the key "playbackBufferEmpty". I placed a log

> NSLog(@"___path: %@", path)

in the first line of the function

> observeValueForKeyPath.....

and the log I received is:

```
...
2012-10-29 17:24:35.412 NhacSo[236:907] ___path: rate
2012-10-29 17:24:35.413 NhacSo[236:907] ___path: playbackLikelyToKeepUp
2012-10-29 17:24:35.415 NhacSo[236:907] ___path: playbackBufferEmpty
2012-10-29 17:24:35.416 NhacSo[236:907] ___path: rate
...
```

Do you know why I receive "playbackLikelyToKeepUp" before "playbackBufferEmpty"? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

You receive playbackLikelyToKeepUp first because that property changes first. What I believe is confusing you is that it changes from YES to NO and not the other way around - that is, playback will no longer be able to keep up.